# Are all functions and aspects of the city of London’s operations subject to judicial review?

Tags: judicial-review, city-of-london

Alfred submits a freedom of information request to the city of London in relation to its management of Hampstead Heath which is rejected due to city’s cash funded functions being exempt therefrom.

Bob objects to aspects of guildhall’s management of the heath and would like to challenge certain decisions via judicial review. Is this Avenue of recourse available to Bob given that city’s cash is not treated in certain contexts as a public body?

Comment: It is for background and context to establish the premise that there is a differentiation between various aspects of the organisation as to when they are treated as a public body.

Comment: For FOIA purposes some aspects are not so treated. For others is it the same?

Comment: I think the last sentence basically makes this clear.

Comment: Judicial Review can be used to challenge a decision made by a public body or another body exercising public law functions. The challenge is on the basis of how the decision was made, not the right or wrong of the decision. Which decision does Bob want to challenge? Permission for judicial review has been granted in at least two cases pertaining to Hampstead Heath: (1) entry charges for swimmers and (2) reservoir safety works.